# HttpServletResponseWrapper Status Code = 0

Tags: java, jax-rs, servlet-filters, weblogic-10.x

I am using HttpServletResponseWrapper to capture the status code in a servlet filter. It seems to work fine.

I get a status of 200 when everything is ok. However when the app server cant find the requested item, I get back a 0. but in the browser it shows up as a 404.

Can someone explain this?

EDIT: This is a JAX-RS web app so I am guessing that if the app server can't match the path it returns without setting a status, then when the webserver see a status of 0 it replaces it with 404. Does this sound right?

Comment: Does your Weblogic support Servlet 3.0?

Comment: I know nothing about Weblogic. It was a Yes-No question. Just answer Yes or No. The real answer depends on that. Now, once again: Does your Weblogic support Servlet 3.0? Yes or No?

Answer (score 0):

I am late but probably the answer is still useful:

In the HttpServletResponseWrapper these methods need to be implemented:

```
@Override
    public void setStatus(int status) {

        super.setStatus(status);    
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(int status) throws IOException {

        this.status = status;
        super.sendError(status);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(int status, String msg) throws IOException {

        this.status = status;
        super.sendError(status, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {

        this.status = 302;
        super.sendRedirect(location);
    }
```

On case of 404 the setStatus is not called but sendError, you need to catch the status there.